# Android webview height not updated if last content was bigger

Tags: android, webview

I searched a lot for my question, but I didn't find exactly answer. I want my **webview** to load different urls each time. When previous html content is bigger than last content, the **webview** is not updating its height. 
The bigger content:
[image]

After loading smaller html content, **webview** height not updating:
[image]

I called **webview**'s invalidate method, but not working. Any idea?